# Animated.spring finish event

Tags: react-native

I am trying to figure out when the Animated.spring event has completed so I can update some state.

I have tried this,  but finish throws an undefined error here;

```
         Animated.spring(
            this.state.pan,
            { toValue: { x: 0, y: -500 } }
          ).start().finish(
            this.setState({
              carousel: false, hasNotification: false
            })
          );
```

Any other methods for dealing with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.39/docs/animations.html#animations)

> start takes a completion callback that will be called when the animation is done. If the animation is done because it finished running normally, the completion callback will be invoked with {finished: true}, but if the animation is done because stop was called on it before it could finish (e.g. because it was interrupted by a gesture or another animation), then it will receive {finished: false}.

So I think this should work:

```
Animated.spring(this.state.pan, { toValue: { x: 0, y: -500 } }).start(()=>{
        this.setState({
          carousel: false, hasNotification: false
        })
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an optional callback:

```
Animated.spring(
            this.state.pan,
            { toValue: { x: 0, y: -500 } }
          ).start(this.stopAnimation.bind(this))

stopAnimation()
{
  this.setState({
      carousel: false, hasNotification: false
  })
}
```